# Is it possible to stimulate the EPOC process?

Tags: metabolism, breathing

On Wikipedia, EPOC is defined as:

> Excess post-exercise oxygen consumption (EPOC, informally called afterburn) is a measurably increased rate of oxygen intake following strenuous activity intended to erase the body's "oxygen deficit".

My question is what influence has post exercise habits on the efficiency of this process?
For example, after an intense exercise, a person rests in bed during this process, consuming a very low amount of oxygen.
Would this process be stimulated if this person would ride the bike for 30 minutes, very slow, but enough to put the cardio-respiratory system at work?